# Plain Text and Cipher Text terminology when double encrypting?

Tags: encryption, terminology

Say I have some message like "Hello World" that I want to encrypt, I get that Hello World is the Plain Text and the output from the encryption is called Cipher Text.

But, let's say I want to encrypt the data again, so I feed in the cipher Text from first round back into the encryption algorithm and then get the new cipher text out.

Effectively I have.

PlainText1 -> EncryptRun1 -> CipherText1

CipherText1 -> EncryptRun2 -> CipherText2

So my question is, when we do the 2nd encryption, do we refer to the input as plain text or is it cipher text? From the algorithms point of view it is plain text but from users perspective it is cipher test.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to use double encryption (I can't remember having done that), I'd call CipherText1 the intermediate ciphertext.

Comment: In [Schneier's Applied Cryptography](https://mrajacse.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/applied-cryptography-2nd-ed-b-schneier.pdf) Section 15.2, he uses the term intermediate value.